# Action Listener help across panels

Tags: java, swing, listener

Ok here is my question. I am writing a program which takes 4 panels combines them into one with a user input in the west, totals in the east, and a banner in the north. my question is how do i implement an action listener to get the numbers that someone is typing in the west panel  to automatically show up in the totals (east) panel? The code is a little long (for me) and I am getting close with this and just want to get it done. Do I have to put the event handler class in the user info panel, or just have it all in the totals panel? I checked out the other questions and could not find an answer.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


/**
*
* User input panel 
* first panel
* has JTextFields for input of date for the hw/h, hours, and gallons
**/

public class UserInput extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    //variables/attributes
    private double kwh;
    private double hours;
    private double gallons;
    public double total;

    //JFrame componants
    private final  JTextField kwhField;
    private final  JTextField hoursField;
    private final  JTextField gallonsField;
    private final JLabel kwhLabel;
    private final JLabel hoursLabel;
    private final JLabel gallonsLabel;


    public UserInput()
    {
        // create the Grid
        setLayout (new GridLayout (3,2));

        //create the fields
        kwhField = new JTextField(15);
        hoursField = new JTextField(15);
        gallonsField = new JTextField(15);

        //create the labels
        kwhLabel = new JLabel ("Kw/H");
        hoursLabel = new JLabel ("Hours");
        gallonsLabel = new JLabel ("Gallons");

        //Add a border
        TitledBorder titled;
        titled = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("User Input");

        //Add the tiles into the grid
        add(kwhField);
        add(kwhLabel);
        add(hoursField);
        add(hoursLabel);
        add(gallonsField);
        add(gallonsLabel);

        //add action listeners
        kwhLabel.addActionListener(this);
    }

    //The get method to retrieve the user inputs
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



/**
 *
 * @return
 */
public double getKwh()
    {
        return kwh;
    }

/**
 *
 * @param k
 */
public void setKwh(double k)
    {
        kwh = k;
    }
    public void setHours (double h)
    {
        hours = h;
    }

    public double getHours ()
    {
        return hours;
    }

/**
 *
 * @param g
 */
public void getGallons(double g)
    {
        gallons = g;
    }

public double setGallons()
{
    return gallons;
}

//Now add action listeners??? we will try it


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of             
}
```

Comment: You should add a `keyListener` to your project. You can read about them [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).

Comment: Updating one part of UI by the input of another part is usually done with observer pattern

Comment: That is good but beyond my capabilities right now, is there any other way to type in the user  fields and have the information mirrored to the totals field through an action listener? and does the action listener have to be together? could I not use a getter for this? the code has a set method.

Comment: Also not sure exactly where your problem lies. For one you have posted no code. Secondly, your description does not really provide a clear picture of what you are talking about. See how to [Write an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you don't provide _all_ your code, you write a completely new simple program, replicating the issues/problems you are facing. This will help us get a clearer picture of what exactly it is you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Sorry my first time here, would I have to add another question or just edit this one to add code?

Comment: The totals panel will just receive the input from this (unfinished) class in the same package. I am unsure on where to put the action listener if I even need one to get the data from this to the totals panel.

Comment: Oh my, I see where your problem is. You want to try an get input from the `Scanner`, is that it? And then get that input to a component?

Comment: YES, but the recieving componant is on another panel that is in the same package... the panels will be placed on another one to make one GUI. I am in this class only 3 weeks and already...DUH...

Comment: First of all you shouldn't be trying to combine console with GUI programming. The thing you need to understand about GUI programming is that it is event driven. Meaning that some user caused event caused some action in a component. It should not be determined by anything going on the console. You could though, add a listener to a text field, and when the user types something in the text field, or when the use hits ENTER after typing in the field, some change will be made to a component. Maybe a little more description on the exact requirements will help to get some suggestions.

Comment: i understand if i am not coming across clearly, i am new to java. The above code will/should make a panel that i will place on the west side of another panel, the total panel on the east side and have a person type their input on the west panel and the total come out on the east panel.  Dont know console sorry if i confused you.

Comment: But yes that is what i am trging to do with an action listener, i just dont know where to put the event listener, where you would type, or on he totals panel wherethe result should go

Answer (score 0):

First Create a JLabel and add it to your east panel to write the typed text. You can add a keylistener to your text field. Override Key Typed method and get the typed key from event by using event.getKeyChar method and write it to on JLabel.

below is some example code from [This Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

```
public class KeyEventDemo ...  implements KeyListener ... {
    ...//where initialization occurs:
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.addKeyListener(this);


    ...
    /** Handle the key typed event from the text field. */
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // HERE You will Write Your Code

    }

    /** Handle the key-pressed event from the text field. */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    /** Handle the key-released event from the text field. */
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. Could i not have an action listener that would automatically get the data from the user input panel and put it into the totals panel? The keylistener and focus stuff is above me.

Comment: If you want to have an action listener then you can add a button on your panel and addActionListener to that button. After keying in your text in textfield. press button and in action listener's actionPerformed get the value from textField and write it into the JLabel.

Comment: Thank you but it needs to happin automatically. Not with a calculate button.

Comment: Than you need to go with KeyListener Only .. ActionListener does not work that way.